# Como exibir dados de um TXT no meu arrayList - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, memória, arraylist, txt

**Atualmente eu faço assim:**

```
ArrayList<produtoItem> lista = new ArrayList<produtoItem>();

lista.add(new produtoItem(R.drawable.imagem, "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA"));

adapter = new produtoAdapter(this, lista);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**A PERGUNTA É: Como usar um TXT como "BANCO DE DADOS"?**

Eu preciso inserir mais de 3000 itens, o que gera o erro: **method code too large**.
Acredito que usando um TXT como "BANCO DE DADOS" vai resolver o meu problema.

**OBS: Esse app precisa funcionar sem a necessidade de internet. Ou seja, não posso usar um banco dados externo.**

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite